# hide select option in modal window jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a calendar with the code below. When the user clicks on a date, it expands and displays time slots available with a book appointment button for each. The user clicks on the button and a modal window displays with a form. One of the fields is a select dropdown where I'd like to hide one of the options.

#### Code on main/parent page

```
jQuery(document).ready
(
function($)
{
    //$("select[name~='2284733'] option[value='187']").hide();
    $("select[name*='2284733']").on('click',
    function ()
    {
        $(this).option[value='187'].hide();
    }
    );
});
```

#### Code in modal window

```
<select name="service-label---2284733">
    <option value="">Select a Product</option>
    <option value="187">Rock Climbing Wall</option>
    <option value="183">Synthetic Ice</option>
    <option value="151">$35 - Sports Simulator</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element is added to the page with javascript, which is usually what happens in a modal box, you need to attach a click event to the document:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // $("select[name~='2284733'] option[value='187']").hide();
    $(document).on('click', 'select[name*="2284733"]', function () {

        $(this).find('option[value="187"]').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks! I just had to change the single quotes to double quotes for name*=

Comment: Recently tried this in Safari 8 Mac and IE 10 PC, and unfortunately the full list displays. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have to start a new post do I?

Comment: @spiderling probably best to start a new post, with as much detail about the problem as possible